# ADMIN LTE II in Rails App, Sidebar and Control sidebar don't collapse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidebar, adminlte

I have a Rails (v5.1) app with ADMIN LTE (v2.3.8) Bootstrap template files in. The collapse function of the sidebar menu on the left does not work.

The click event listener for the toggleBtn is working properly, because when I click it it logs "Click on offcanvas" in the console. Furthermore when I inspect the body tag on click of the toggleBtn it highlights but doesn't toggle the 'sidebar-collapse'class as it's supposed to.

**app/assets/javascripts/AdminLTE.js**

```
$.AdminLTE.pushMenu = {
    activate: function (toggleBtn) {
      //Get the screen sizes
      var screenSizes = $.AdminLTE.options.screenSizes;

      //Enable sidebar toggle
      $(document).on('click', toggleBtn, function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          //Enable sidebar push menu
          console.log("Click on offcanvas")
        if ($(window).width() > (screenSizes.sm - 1)) {
          if ($("body").hasClass('sidebar-collapse')) {
              $("body").removeClass('sidebar-collapse').trigger('expanded.pushMenu');
          } else {
            $("body").addClass('sidebar-collapse').trigger('collapsed.pushMenu');
          }
        }
        //Handle sidebar push menu for small screens
        else {
          if ($("body").hasClass('sidebar-open')) {
            $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open').removeClass('sidebar-collapse').trigger('collapsed.pushMenu');
          } else {
            $("body").addClass('sidebar-open').trigger('expanded.pushMenu');
          }
        }
      });

      $(".content-wrapper").click(function () {
        //Enable hide menu when clicking on the content-wrapper on small screens
        if ($(window).width() <= (screenSizes.sm - 1) && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-open")) {
          $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open');
        }
      });

      //Enable expand on hover for sidebar mini
      if ($.AdminLTE.options.sidebarExpandOnHover
        || ($('body').hasClass('fixed')
        && $('body').hasClass('sidebar-mini'))) {
        this.expandOnHover();
      }
    },
    expandOnHover: function () {
      var _this = this;
      var screenWidth = $.AdminLTE.options.screenSizes.sm - 1;
      //Expand sidebar on hover
      $('.main-sidebar').hover(function () {
        if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-mini')
          && $("body").hasClass('sidebar-collapse')
          && $(window).width() > screenWidth) {
          _this.expand();
        }
      }, function () {
        if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-mini')
          && $('body').hasClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover')
          && $(window).width() > screenWidth) {
          _this.collapse();
        }
      });
    },
    expand: function () {
      $("body").removeClass('sidebar-collapse').addClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover');
    },
    collapse: function () {
      if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover')) {
        $('body').removeClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover').addClass('sidebar-collapse');
      }
    }
  };
```

**application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require AdminLTE
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <title>TrailerApp</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDrNW2yzxeYgYARA67ss3pX1p0yq7ZzFhI&libraries=places&language=es' %>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-yellow">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <header class="main-header">
  <!-- Logo -->
  <a href="/" class="logo">
    <span class="logo-mini"><b>T</b>J</span>
    <span class="logo-lg"><b>Trailer</b>App</span>
  </a>

  <!-- Header Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
    <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
    <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        ...
        <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<aside class="main-sidebar">
  <section class="sidebar">
     ....
  </section>
</aside>
```

**Gemfile**

```
...
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.0.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon your question while I was looking for AdminLTE related questions. I have been recently porting the AdminLTE framework to Rails framwork and I think I already solved this issue.

Please check out the [Link](https://github.com/mekutr/AdminLTEOnRails)

I know it is a bit late for your answer but I just wanted to answer it anyways. Hope it helps